# Chrome address bar using Yahoo not Google if starting search with Mcafee

Tags: google-chrome

So I've a new laptop, it's win10, and it came preloaded with Mcafee Livesafe 30 day trial. It was bugging me about buying the full product, so I thought I'd remove it, when searching for what it was, my Chrome address bar did this:

I type Mcafee, then after hitting space it morphed my "Mcafee" to "Search Mcafee" and then what ever I type comes after this prefix. The search is then provided by Yahoo not Google, google being the case with all other searches.

I have uninstalled Mcafee Livesafe now, and I have checked Chrome for any Mcafee or Yahoo extensions to which there are none. Its really confusing me why or how its doing this.

Comment: Isn't Yahoo results provided by Google?

Comment: I don't know about that, also the second option on the drop down will search Google. but this automatic yahoo search is bothering me, especially as I don't appear to have anything installed that should be causing it.

Comment: I think your default search engine is set to Yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *resetting* your browser?

Type : `chrome://settings/resetProfileSettings` into your address bar, and when the page loads hit the reset button. This should get rid of this search bar intrusion.

Comment: hi, I tried as you suggested but it made no difference.

Comment: http://www.superantispyware.com/superantispyware.html this program is usually quite good at removing unwanted search preferences.

Comment: This software found a lot of tracking cookies only, and after cleaning them I still have the problem. Think I'm going for a reinstall of Chome next.

Comment: Try reading this thread https://community.mcafee.com/thread/74654?start=10&tstart=0

Comment: Right that sounds like I'm not the only one banging head against a wall with this then. Secure Search is off, but mcafee>yahoo still commands my omnibox.